# Do System background tasks in Windows 7 run throttled?

Tags: windows-7, tasks

I am trying to Trace installations, to do that I have to wait for the "systems background tasks" to cool out. Or it traces all the system tasks going on. It can take a some time to finish all the tasks at the rate it is working.

The stuff DOES finish when given time, but then I revert time again (backup) to test a different way. so It is not terrible or never ending, I just have to wait after a reboot or install to trace the next install.

The activity I am seeing Seems to be throttled or limited to ~100k , my system can do 200M max (raid0), sometimes it jumps up in speed.  It just feels/looks like it from the graphs and perf data.   There is very limited CPU use, and the system is 64-bit version, the CPU is a quad core.

can anybody confirm?

I also saw in passing a thread on changing this throttle, so these background task can get done, and out of the way. But now I cannot find it :-(  I hope this is a duplicate post and I just don't know the correct terminology to search it.

If a limiter or throttle of any kind exists, is there a way to adjust that? Is there a command like in XP, to manually start the background performance stuff?

I started applying "suspend" of a task for the first time in my life, but some items will not complete install with a thing called Svhosts (localsystem network restricted) suspended?? I cant very well suspend System.

I am not tracing because I know what I am doing, I am tracing so I can Undo things completely, even years later,  it was easy before.

I could assume WHY they would throttle the CPU use or disk activity, its a good thing usually, just not at this time.

Example things in the way of tracing:  .PNFs being made from .INIs (then I add in more drivers) Prefetch creation (then I run a few more programs).
 The usual logs, recovery, driver depository, MRUs in the registry, other massive registry internals, things related to the big WSXS backup piles. Installing a driver causes a lot of activity, but most of it backup background type.

Sysrestore, defender, and indexing and others, I have mostly stopped for a while,  thanks  to Q-As here, which doesn't help test a normal system :-) but close enough.

Comment: Well, check the priorities with Proccess Explorer. Also, you can check them out with "CPU Lasso", and/or adjust their priority permanently. Just my two cents.

Comment: Does windows 7 do priority different than XP?  There is very little cpu use also, I have never seen anything so well controlled :-) hmm It is a 64bit version.

Comment: Uhm, I don't think so. Basically what I saw running in the background from time to time is the .net optimization service. Besides that, nothing else waiting/hogging. But the system processes are set to "low" priority AFAIK. So try getting the trial CPU Lasso, and set them to highest. Maybe.

Comment: @Shiki process lasso?

Comment: It's an application. http://bitsum.com/prolasso.php

Answer (score 0):

This isnt a complete answer.  Thanks (again) to info from users here, I traced it down to superfetch being one of the main items that continues operating after boot.
Superfetch, is one of the items I had not turned off yet.
On my particular machine, the action of superfetch was to pre-load about 300-400megs, as (only) loosly observed in the quantity of memory usage. Superfetch did not operate very slowly and controlled, it wildly opens up many tasks, during its operations.

More research on windows development suggest that things are definatly  controlled, so they work in the background without bothering the users normal operations, they did not use the word throttle.